# androidscrollview top and right border space issue

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

my layout is like this and result image is below

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/gamelobby"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/gamelobby_bg" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/banner"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/banner"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:typeface="serif"
      android:textColor="#e3ab15"
      android:text="My Banner"
      android:textSize="22sp"/>
   //my other layout
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Here the back ground is not an image it's a shape drawable whose xml code is like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#523c00"
        android:endColor="#100c00"
        android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

As you can see there is a gap between top screen and banner and also between right side banner and screen.i want to remove those.i searched a lot and also tried many approaches, not working. any help!!!! thanks

Comment: check that if there is not a transparent part in banner image...

Comment: @SanketKachhela checked already it's not a image it's a shape drawable.

Comment: @SanketKachhela edited the question please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try settings both the layout_margin and layout_padding to "0dp".  My guess would be that you are picking up some styling from your app's theme.

Comment: though good guess not working, but it's working for other screen fine because in those screens, bar is not inside scrollview, here it is inside and it is the need.

Answer (score 0):

May be it help you.  android:layout_marginTop="-5dip" and android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gamelobby"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:layout_marginTop="-2dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip">
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/banner"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="My Banner"
  android:textColor="#e3ab15"
  android:textSize="22sp"
  android:typeface="serif" />

  //my other layout
 </RelativeLayout>
```